# Exception on Bulk upload with Entity framework C# MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement a bulk upload functionality of employees in my application using entity framework. But facing an exception with SaveChanges() method.

```
public void UploadEmployees(List<Employee> employees)
    {
        try
        {
            SalesERPDB salesDal = new SalesERPDB();
            salesDal.Employees.AddRange(employees);
            salesDal.SaveChanges(); **// Getting an exception in this line**
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

SalesERPDB class:

```
public class SalesERPDB:DbContext
{
    public SalesERPDB() : base("SalesERPDB")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees {get; set;}
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("TblEmployee");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Employee Class:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [FirstNameValidation]
    public string FName { get; set; }
    [FirstNameValidation]
    [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage="Last Name length should not be greater than 5")]
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

What exactly i need to make sure that SaveChanges() method is executed with the upload functionality without any exception.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: Write down the exception you receive.

Comment: What is the exception? Please provide more details.

Comment: @OldTrain Have updated the query with the exception details

Comment: @Reddy Have updated the query with the exception details

Comment: seems like the data you are trying to save into DB does not pass the validation logic as per your Model design with custom Atrributes.

Comment: As you are writing all validation errors to console using Console.WriteLine, what are all the validations errors do you see in the console? How do you run this code? As part of a console application or web application?

Comment: @Reddy Yes. The data i was pushing to get updated was not satisfying one of my custom validation attribute. Thanks.

Comment: @Manju glad you found the issue. happy coding!!